# Need help redirecting through PHP

Tags: php, html, redirect, survey

I'm currently building a survey. I've made quite a bit of progress so far. If a participant completes and submits the survey it successfully enters my database and returns the participant to the main page of my site but if one question is skipped by the participant, when they try to submit the survey it returns a blank display and no data is fed into my database.

I want to create a survey that gives participants the ability to skip questions, and returns them to the homepage after submitting the survey.

I understand it may be easy for some but I'm fairly new to PHP so I'm still learning, please see the code below.

```
<?php
$radioVal1 = $_POST["q1"];
$radioVal2 = $_POST["q2"];
$radioVal3 = $_POST["q3"];
$radioVal4 = $_POST["q4"];
$radioVal5 = $_POST["q5"];
$checkboxVal6 = $_POST["q6"];
$textAreaVal = $_POST["comment"];
session_start();
require_once('DBConnection.php');
if(isset($_POST["submit_questionnaire"])){
    if(isset($_POST["q1"]) && isset($_POST["q2"]) && isset($_POST["q3"]) && isset($_POST["q4"]) && isset($_POST["q5"]) && isset($_POST["q6"]) && $textAreaVal!=null){
        echo "blyat";
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $db = new DBConnection();
        $conn= $db::getInstance()->dbConnect();
        $query_code = "SELECT id_code FROM users WHERE name = '$username'";
        $id_codeRow = $db::getInstance()->selectDB($query_code)->fetch_row();
        $id_code = (string)array_values($id_codeRow)[0];
        $query = "INSERT INTO questionnaire VALUES (default, '$id_code', '$radioVal1', '$radioVal2', '$radioVal3','$radioVal4', '$radioVal5', '$checkboxVal6', '$textAreaVal')";
        $insert_value = $db::getInstance()->selectDB($query);
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }

}
```

Comment: its because the ```insert``` into db and the redirection doesn't happen if the very long if statement isn't true so you need to do for example redirect to ```index.php``` anyways if the if statement is true or not

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

**// You can remplace "&&" by "OR" so any questions can be skipped by the user but the user have to complete atleast 1 question.**

```
<?php
$radioVal1 = $_POST["q1"];
$radioVal2 = $_POST["q2"];
$radioVal3 = $_POST["q3"];
$radioVal4 = $_POST["q4"];
$radioVal5 = $_POST["q5"];
$checkboxVal6 = $_POST["q6"];
$textAreaVal = $_POST["comment"];
session_start();
require_once('DBConnection.php');
if(isset($_POST["submit_questionnaire"])){
    if(isset($_POST["q1"]) OR isset($_POST["q2"]) OR isset($_POST["q3"]) OR isset($_POST["q4"]) OR isset($_POST["q5"]) OR isset($_POST["q6"])){
        echo "blyat";
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $db = new DBConnection();
        $conn= $db::getInstance()->dbConnect();
        $query_code = "SELECT id_code FROM users WHERE name = '$username'";
        $id_codeRow = $db::getInstance()->selectDB($query_code)->fetch_row();
        $id_code = (string)array_values($id_codeRow)[0];
        $query = "INSERT INTO questionnaire VALUES (default, '$id_code', '$radioVal1', '$radioVal2', '$radioVal3','$radioVal4', '$radioVal5', '$checkboxVal6', '$textAreaVal')";
        $insert_value = $db::getInstance()->selectDB($query);
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }

}
```